# Where to define class constants in C++?

Tags: c++, header, refactoring, constants, compile-time-constant

In C++, to have a tidier code, I want to declare a set of values as constants in my header file, example :

```cpp
constexpr float SIZE_SMALL = 1.5f; 
constexpr float SIZE_MEDIUM = 2.5f; 
constexpr std::string COLOR_RED = "RED"; 
constexpr std::string MATERIAL_SILK = "SILK";
...etc
```

But this is getting too long and clumsy. Also, some constants can be grouped together because they describe different values of the same property e.g. `SIZE_SMALL` and `SIZE_MEDIUM`.

What is the best way to write this in my header file? I thought about structs e.g.

```cpp
struct SIZE
{
float SMALL; 
float MEDIUM; 
}
```

but then I have to declare and define a variable in my .cpp and that kinda beats the purpose of all this.

Comment: Could you explain _"But this is getting too long and clumsy"_ please? I'd d'ont necessarily see why. I'd group those constants by semantic, putting them in nested namespaces eventually `namespace size { constexpr float small = 1.5f; }`.

Comment: what about `static constexpr` member variable?

Comment: @YSC, I have some 50+ of these constants in the same name space

Comment: Well, namespaces are free you know.

Comment: oh, you mean a namespace inside a namespace? sounds good

Comment: you should declare all your namespace/global scope variables in your header inline. otherwise every translationunit gets its own copy of the variable and you may violate the one definition rule of other inline functions which use these variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on your actual usage but [consider using proper strong types](https://foonathan.net/2016/10/strong-typedefs/) instead of basic types. For instance, to declare sizes, make them of type `size`, not `float`. This doesn’t *directly* solve your grouping problem but it gives you all of the other benefits of strong typing, and may also help with grouping:

```
struct size {
private: float value;
public:
    explicit constexpr size(float value) : value{value} {}
    explicit constexpr operator float() const noexcept { return value; }
};

namespace default_sizes {
    constexpr auto SMALL = size{1.5f};
    constexpr auto MEDIUM = size{2.5f};
    // …
}
```

In fact, for domain-specific usage, except in very limited cases, I’d *generally* avoid bare basic types and always encapsulate them in their own domain-specific type.

Comment: is it possible to initiate an enum with anything other than ints?

Comment: @FakherMokadem Yes, [you can use non-`int`s as the underlying type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), but they still need to be integral types. Note that I didn’t say “use an enum” (because you can’t), I suggested to “*imitate* an enum”.

Answer (score 6):

> then I have to declare and define a variable in my .cpp and that kinda beats the purpose of all this.

No you dont. You can make the fields `static` and `constexpr` :

```
struct SIZES {
    static constexpr const float SMALL = 1.5f;
};
```

However, I recommend to not do this. Not only you do not have to create an instance of this class, but also you should not create an instance of this class (what for?). So why use a class in the first place? Use `namespace`s instead to group constants:

```
namespace SIZES {
    constexpr float SMALL = 1.5f; 
}
```

> I have some 50+ of these constants in the same name space

Unless you find a way to make the compiler read your mind, you have to write them all down somewhere. Serisously, the only way this could be condesned is if there is some relation between those constants, as eg `SMALL + 1.0f = MEDIUM`, but thats not apparent from your question.

Comment: ok for the namespace (y). But if I define a struct -with the static and constexpr fields- without declaring an instance, how will I use that stuct in the code?

Comment: @FakherMokadem The point of `static` members is that you _don't_ need an instance to access them...

Comment: @FakherMokadem `SIZES::SMALL`, btw I just suggeted you to **not** use static const members of a struct...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I don't think that you need a `const` next to the `constexpr`. For variables, the `constexpr` is also a `const`. It is mentioned in Effective Modern C++, by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos I am not sure if it has any effect, still I like to have it there. At least it has an effect on someone not yet familiar with `constexpr`. How much this makes sense, depends on who will read your code (for me it does)

Comment: In C++17: `inline constexpr float SMALL = 1.5f;`